# How to access the detail object when writing to a nested serializer on a ModelViewSet action?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-deserialization

I'm having trouble using actions to populate a nested serializer.
I have a parent model called Allocation, and a child model, Trade (one-to-many).

I have a `ModelViewset` for Allocation, and I want it to have an action method that allows me to post the JSON containing a list of Trades, and create them with the relation to the parent model populated.

How do I access the parent's object or PK  on my `TradeSerializer` so I can populate it's `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

```py
class AllocationViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AllocationSerializer
    queryset = Allocation.trades.all()
    lookup_field = "reference_date"

    # The detail=True makes the url allocation/2022-07-25/import_pre_allocation/
    # The 2022-07-25 uniquely identifies my allocation instance.
    @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
    def import_pre_allocation(self, request, reference_date=None):
        allocation_obj = self.get_object()

        # here I`m trying to pass my parent object as a context element
        serializer = TradeSerializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'allocation_pk': allocation_obj.pk})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            for trade in serializer.validated_data:
                trade["allocation"] = allocation_obj
            print(serializer.data)

            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```py
class TradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quantity = serializers.DecimalField(required=False, max_digits=Trade.TRADE_QUANTITY_MAX_DIGITS, decimal_places=Trade.TRADE_QUANTITY_DECIMAL_PLACES)
    allocation = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, required=False,queryset=Allocation.objects.all())

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # How do I populate my allocation field with the allocation_obj received from context?
        allocation_obj = Allocation.objects.get(pk=self.request.allocation_pk)
        serializer.save(allocation=allocation_obj)
        
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ["allocation","quantity"]
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to pass the parent and save it in the child serializer, you could try something like this:

```
class TradeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  allocation = AllocationSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Trade
    exclude = ('id',)

  def create(self, attrs):
    instance = super(TradeSerializer, self).create(attrs)
    instance.allocation = self.initial_data.get('allocation')
    instance.save()
```

and just make sure in your view to pass the id of the allocation